# fullcalendar_rails put more information on Agenda

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, fullcalendar

I have the following problem just put me the title of the event and the date , but I need you to show me more fields.

if I change the index.json.jbuilder and put it in this way :(  json.title    event.user.email) instead of the title show me the mail appears , but I need you to show me the :user, :title , :sala, :materia.

_event.json.jbuider

```
date_format = event.all_day_event? ? '%Y-%m-%d' : '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
json.extract! event, :id, :title, :sala, :materia, :user_id

json.start event.start.strftime(date_format)
json.end event.end.strftime(date_format)

json.color event.color unless event.color.blank?
json.allDay event.all_day_event? ? true : false

json.update_url event_path(event, method: :patch)
json.edit_url edit_event_path(event)
```

_index.json.jbuider

```
json.array! @events do |event|
  json.extract! event, :id, :title, :sala, :materia, :user_id
  date_format = event.all_day_event? ? '%Y-%m-%d' : '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'


  json.start event.start.strftime(date_format)
  json.end event.end.strftime(date_format)
  json.color event.color unless event.color.blank?
  json.allDay event.all_day_event? ? true : false
  json.update_url event_path(event, method: :patch)
  json.edit_url edit_event_path(event)
end
```

fullcalendar_js

```
var initialize_calendar;
initialize_calendar = function() {
  $('.calendar').each(function(){
    var calendar = $(this);
    calendar.fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      defaultView: 'agendaDay',
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      slotDuration: '00:60:00',
      slotEventOverlap: false,
      forceEventDuration: true,
      minTime: '08:00:00',
      maxTime: '20:00:00',
      hiddenDays: [ 6, 7 ],
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true,
      events: '/events.json',

};
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', initialize_calendar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eventRender: function(event, element) { 
              element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.sala); 
          } ,
```